# How can I apply no-disposable when programmatically adding a user with wp_insert_user()?

Tags: plugins, user-registration

How can I run no-disposable-emails plugin when programmatically adding a user with wp_insert_user()?

I mean how does that work?

http://wordpress.org/plugins/no-disposable-email/

```
    $random_password = wp_generate_password( 8, false );

    $user_data = array(
                                    'user_login'  => $sanitized_user_login,
                                    'user_pass' => wp_generate_password ( 7, false ),
                                    'first_name'  => $first_name,
                                    'last_name' => $last_name,
                                    'user_email'  => $email,
                                    'display_name'  => $first_name . ' ' . $last_name,
                                    'nickname'  => $first_name . ' ' . $last_name,
                                    'role'    => 'TestDrive',
                                    'city'=>$city,
                                    'state'=>$state,
                                    'country'=>$country
                    );

    $user_id = wp_insert_user($user_data);
```

HERE what worked for me:

```
    $errors = new WP_Error();
    $check_disposable = no_disposable_email($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $email);
    $error_string = $check_disposable->get_error_message();

    if (!$error_string)) {
            $user_id = wp_insert_user($user_data);
    } else {
            die("Please do not use disposable email for registering!");
    }
```

Comment: What is `var-dump($check_disposable);`?

Comment: thanks for the tip, I didn't even know about this one, but didn't need it afterall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the plugin you mention does is apply a filter to [`registration_errors`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/no-disposable-email/trunk/no-disposable-email.php#L84), which is used by a function called [`register_new_user`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1661). The quickest and easiest solution would be to use that function instead of `wp_insert_user`.

If that isn't possible or your code design doesn't allow it, you can always call `no_disposable_email` directly, and before `wp_insert_user`.

```
$errors = new WP_Error();
$sanitized_user_login = 'login';
$user_email = 'email@example.com';
$check_disposable = no_disposable_email($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email);
If (!is_wp_error($check_disposable)) {
  // wp_insert_user
} else {
  // whatever you need
}
```

Very bare-bones code sample, but should get you started.

Comment: small typo: is_wp_error instead of wp_error ... yet this condition always fall in my 'else' section. See updates in my question

Comment: So, you marked this "accepted". Can I ask why? your last comments make it seem like you are still having issues.

Comment: certainly, I will update my question accordingly, basically I tested $error_string = $check_disposable->get_error_message();